# Why Atom editor continuously show this 'not recognized....' error?

Tags: atom-editor

I am new to Atom editor. When i want to run JS code in Atom, it continuously show an error message.
`'C:\Users\Fahran' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
How can i fix it. Maybe this script package cause the error. But don't know how to fix it.

[image: I use this script package]

[image]

Comment: Does this still happen after you saved your document?

Comment: @idleberg, Yes same thing happened all the time. Can you please help me to fix it or is there any alternative of script package?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the FAQ on the atom site [regarding executing code](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-do-i-build-or-execute-code-ive-written-in-atom/25341) on atom? Additionally, [check this out](https://discuss.atom.io/t/beginner-question-how-to-preview-run-javascript-in-atom/46433)

Atom's packaging system is very well built. You should be able to browse for a similar build package for JS and try it out.